Coordinate transformation for Dirac delta distribution
There are multiple posts in here discussing the behaviour of the Dirac distribution under some change of coordinates. However, I didn't find any that directly dealt with what I'm facing at the moment.
Suppose you are working in a (Lorentzian) space described by three coordinates $(t,x,z)$ and are considering the distribution $$ \delta(t) \delta(x). $$
How does this distribution transform under the following change of coordinates? The transformation is square but $z$ does not appear in the initial distribution:  $$ t= \dfrac{\sin \tau }{\alpha \sin \rho + \cos \tau}, \, x= \dfrac{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}\sin \rho }{\alpha \sin \rho + \cos \tau}, \,  z= \dfrac{\cos \rho}{ \alpha \sin \rho + \cos \tau}.$$
My initial guess was that $\delta(t) \delta(x) = \int dz\,  \delta(z) \delta(x) \delta(t)$, but I'm not sure I can work it out this way.

Do you have the exact expressions for the transformation?

@md2perpe Yes, I'm editing them now in the question!

Should it be $\tan\rho \cos\rho,$ i.e. $\sin\rho$ in the formula for $x$ or is that a mistake?

You can think of z not appearing in the distribution as having an infinite Dirac delta line along the z-axis.  For any z you have an impulse on the z axis.

@md2perpe, indeed, I don't know why I had written it like this.

@AndyWalls I'm sorry, I'm not sure I see how this allows me to transform to the other system of coordinates

What are the ranges of $\tau,\alpha,\rho$?

$\tau$ and $\alpha$ range from 0 to 2$\pi$ and $\rho$ is a positive real number. These are the global coordinates of AdS$_3$.

How can $\alpha$ range from $0$ to $2\pi$ when there is a factor $\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}$ in the expression for $x$?
